# Remove year from material-ui datepicker

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Right now the only two types of date pickers possible are Date pickers with the full month, day, and year, and datetime pickers. I want to allow my user to select a season rather than a specific range and as such want to remove the year from the Date picker. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: How are you defining a season? It can differ based on geographic location. Perhaps you have a specific need for this date picker option, but is it the only option you have?

Comment: A season as in a date range that a user has specified. For example, January 13- April 23, December 15-February 4. It would be useful to remove the year so that users would not get confused.

Comment: You should look into other date picker packages. material-ui's pickers are pretty bad anyways

Comment: So you're just look for a regular date range picker with `MMDD` formatting?

Comment: Yes, exactly, that's what I'm looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is probably https://github.com/airbnb/react-dates. You can format the dates to display in `MMDD`, for example. This would allow your users to define their own range or "season" as you specified.